# How to get characters after certain characters

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable, `WORKSPACE` which is `/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en`

From each line I'd like to remove it and create a two variables.

For example, from the line,

```
"/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md",
```

to get

```
category=references/architecture/recipes
title=hermit.md
```

The line has different depth:

```
"/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/guides/faq.md",
```

to get

```
category=guides
title=faq.md
```

etc.

I tried the following but it get the last two items only.

```
title=$(basename "$line")
filedirname=$(dirname "$line")
category=$(basename $filedirname)
```

How can I do this with Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the category and title are determined by what is after the `/.vivliostyle/tauri/en` pathname.

Having the following

```
WORKSPACE="/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en"
```

You can use `bash` to get the desired results:

```bash
pathname="${line#$WORKSPACE/}"
#or 
pathname="${line/$WORKSPACE\/}" #replaces $WORKSPACE/ with nothing

#Getting category:
category="${pathname%/*}"
echo "Category: $category"

#Getting title:
title="${pathname##*/}"
echo "Title: $title"
```

So having this path:

```bash
line="/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md"
```

using the code above you will get:

```
Category: references/architecture/recipes
Title: hermit.md
```

and having this path:

```bash
line="/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/guides/faq.md"
```

you get:

```
Category: guides
Title: faq.md
```

**Explanation**

```
pathname="${line#$WORKSPACE/}"
```

With the line above *I'm removing* what `$WORKSPACE/` contains from the `$line` variable.

Therefore,  the string `/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/` will be removed from `/Users/shinichiokada/Bash_Projects/markdown-docs-as-pdf/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md"`. 
The string I got in `$pathname` is:

```
references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md
```

---

```bash
category="${pathname%/*}"
```

The line above will remove all after the last `/` found in the path: `references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md` so what is removed here is `/hermit.md` and the `$category` will contain:

```
references/architecture/recipes
```

---

```
title="${pathname##*/}"
```

The line above will remove all before the last `/` found in the path:
`references/architecture/recipes/hermit.md` so what is removed here is: `references/architecture/recipes/`. Then the `$title` will contain:

```
hermit.md
```

Comment: pathname="${line#*/.vivliostyle/tauri/en/}" is dynamic. Can I use ${WORKSPACE} variable here? tauri can be svelte, react etc.

Comment: @shin sure! I'll update the answer to provide a dynamic solution

Comment: Can you explain about line#$WORKSPACE/ and pathname%/* and pathname##*/? Are they parameter expansions?

Comment: @shin Yes, they are. I will detail what those lines do, However you can use `man bash` or check the following [article](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to learn about **parameter expansions**